# Ubuntu 12.04 won't start after boot menu, but gives startup sound

Tags: 12.04, boot, dual-boot, grub2

As said, I installed Ubuntu 12.04 in dual boot with my previous Windows Vista on my laptop.
I run the boot repair, and did Recommended Repair.
I can get into Windows, but not Ubuntu. Although I can select it on boot menu, then it gives me a black screen, and doesn't pass from this. However, I can hear the sound of the ubuntu startup, but I get no image, only black

Sugestions?

This is the output:
"Boot successfully repaired.

Please write on a paper the following URL:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6147436/

In case you still experience boot problem, indicate this URL to:
boot.repair@gmail.com or to your favorite support forum.

You can now reboot your computer."

Comment: did you try startx?

Comment: I have a black screen, but not a shell. And allegedly, it would go straigh to the user screen.
It's like it is still 'loading'..

Answer (score -1):

first press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> when you logged in normally and then type: `sudo apt-get update`, next `sudo apt-get upgrade` When it finished, type `sudo reboot` and *voilà*

Comment: But I can't log in... I got a blank black screen.

Comment: Yes, in the blank black screen, when you'll hear the sound, you have to do it. If you press ctrl + alt + F1, you will change to "terminal session" :) Try it!

Comment: I tried, several times. No change in the screen :c

Comment: I'm sorry user138513... If you have important data, you could save them with a liveCD and USBs to format all and reinstall ubuntu.